# App Engine Breaks Encoding

Tags: json, google-app-engine, objectify

When I deploy the backend locally and make the call to the apimethod (through url or explorer) I receive a response with this in the JSON:

```
"pronunciations": [  {   
    "type": "ahd-legacy",   
    "pronunciation": "(rēˈstrə)"  
} ]
```

However, the second I deploy it to the app engine and call this method (which stores the object in objectify) and then sends it back in that object format I am receiving this as the JSON:

```
"pronunciations": [  {
    "type": "ahd-legacy",
    "pronunciation": "(r����str��)"
} ]
```

I have also tried storing the string as utf-8 bytes (which objectify automatically converts to base64 which then still converts to the above)

Should I be tagging something specifically so it is stored correctly?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Objectify or the datastore. Whatever String you hand Objectify (and thus the datastore) is what you get back; there is no base-64 encoding going on. If you have encoding problems, you need to look higher up in your stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what it is. The reason why this works fine when run from local and doesn't work when you deploy is because when I made a call to receieve something from an endpoint, it automatically uses the encoding for the server which is ASCII. If you want this to work you need to make your request like this:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
String response = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8")).readLine();

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
return jsonParser.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a storage problem, but more likely an encoding problem at the point where you receive/send data from/to the network and encode/decode it.

JVM on GAE production servers is set to have US-ASCII as default encoding. On your local machine it's probably set to UTF-8.

Whenever you convert between String and byte arrays, you should always explicitly use UTF-8.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try messing with it some more. However, I have already tried using the StringUtils getbytesutf8 and newstringutf8 methods inside of my getter and setter for the object so I'm not sure what else I can try. Thanks!